# SQL: Multiple matches towards same table?

Tags: mysql, view

Probably a very basic solution to this, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to match
multiple ID's in one table towards another.

Structure is something like this,

```
tt_staff (ID - name)
2 - Lenny
3 - Carl

tt_run (producer1 - producer2)
2 (i.e Lenny)
3 (i.e Carl)
```

I want to create a view with a single row that shows me the names of both Carl and Lenny, rather then their ID's.

Tried the following,

```
SELECT e.*, run.*, s.s_name FROM tt_run AS run, tt_events AS e, tt_staff AS s
WHERE e.e_ID = run.e_ID
AND run.e_bandproducer1 = s.s_ID 
AND run.e_bandproducer2 = s.s_ID
```

This obviously doesn't work, since the ID is found on producer1. I've also tried with UNION, but not familiar enough with it (I did manage to get the right result, but in two rows).

As always, thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just need to join tt_staff twice:

```
SELECT e.*, r.*, s1.s_name, s2.s_name
  FROM tt_events e
  INNER JOIN tt_run r ON e.e_ID = r.e_ID
  INNER JOIN tt_staff s1 ON r.e_bandproducer1 = s1.s_ID
  INNER JOIN tt_staff s2 ON r.e_bandproducer2 = s2.s_ID
```

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot! However, I believe I've done this another (and possibly even simpler) way before. Is there some neat trick to this? I'll leave the topic unresolved a short while in case another suggestion is posted.